# Como deixar o fundo da label transparente ? python3 + tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
lbl2 = Label(jan, font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), text="Escolha apenas uma Categoria por vez")
lbl2.place(x=20, y=450)
```

Estou colocando essa Label em cima de uma imagem verde, mais acaba ficando com o fundo dela cinza, existe alguma forma usando o tkinter de deixar apenas o texto ? tipo um fundo transparente.

Ja fiz algumas pesquisas aqui e não conseguir encontrar nada que se encaixe no que estou procurando.

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Eu precisaria de mais detalhes a respeito do seu código para te ajudar com maior certeza de sucesso, mas você pode fazer algo semelhante a isso.

**Crie um Canvas e aplique a imagem dentro dele:**

```
self.canvas = Canvas(root,width=810, height=500, bg="#000000",bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
self.painel = self.canvas.create_image(403,350, image=self.image2)
```

**Coloque o Canvas como uma Camada Inferior**

```
self.canvas.lower(self.painel)
self.canvas.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=0, ipady=20)
```

**Sobrepronha o Canvas com a sua Label ou outro objeto de preferência**

```
retangule = self.canvas.create_rectangle(40,530,220,360,outline="")
```

Segue um link de apoio: [Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm#class-reference)

Answer (score -4):

Label com backgoud="Green" e ele fica transparente.