# Remover fundo de imagem com tkinter

Tags: python, imagem, tkinter

Estou tentando fazer duas camadas com duas imagens em que a de fundo fica inteira no aplicativo, e a segunda se sobrepõe. A segunda é transparente, porém, quando ocorre o display, ele coloca fundo cinza. Como posso tirar esse fundo?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
janela = Tk()

janela.geometry("1920x1080")
janela.title("Mario")

mario = PhotoImage(file = "cenario.png")

label = Label(janela, image = mario).place(x=0,y=0)
photo = PhotoImage(file = "mario.png")
label = Label(janela, image = photo).place(x=3,y=600)

janela.mainloop()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada no widget canvas, existe meios de criar uma label delimitada com ele, tipo desenhada. Olha esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324517/como-deixar-o-fundo-da-label-transparente-python3-tkinter) aqui também.

Comment: Olhei o link, e pelo que entendi preciso criar um canvas e colocar a imagem em cima, mas não estou conseguindo criar o código, e nem encontrar um. Poderia mostrar um código de exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

A unica forma que sei para as imagens ficarem com o fundo transparente é fazendo elas como canvas...

```
from tkinter import *

j = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(j,  bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

image = PhotoImage(file='foto1.png')
image_id2 = canvas.create_image(25,25, image=image)

image2 = PhotoImage(file='foto2.png')
image_id = canvas.create_image(25,60, image=image2)

j.mainloop()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]